# broacast tv specs.

Tags: encoding, transcoding, broadcast

can any one help me about how can i deliver this specs for a broadcast tv channel ? :

im using fcpx and compressor 4. do i need any other app or can i manage it with those ?

which specs i do on fcp and which ones i do on compressor?

File format - IMX/D10
WRAPPER - MXF OP-1A
MPEG-2 GOP stucture - I-FRAME
Chroma Sampling - 4:2:2
Frame Rate - 25
Frame Size - 720 x 576
Audio Levels - -10dBFS (ref)
File Naming Structure - NAME_DURATION
Aspect Ratio - 16x9
Field order - Upper Field - (WHAT IS THIS ?)
AUDIO CHANNELS ( 1 AND 2) - 2 CHANNELS
Sampling Rate - 48000Hz
Sample Format - 16/24 bit

Sory the noobness.